# How can two default dictionaries of lists be merged into one

Tags: python

```
the d1 is  defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [4, 4, 4, 4], 'S': [1]})
the d2 is  defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [4, 4, 4], 'B': [2], '[]': [4, 4]})
```

How to merge these two dictionaries into one?

The expected output should be

```
the d3 is  defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [4], 'B': [2], 'S':[1] ,'[]': [4]})
```

In the resultant dictionary the multiple values should be made into one

Comment: I'd imagine the question was downvoted because the OP didn't show any attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: @kojiro It was probably downvoted because of 'What have you tried?', but I agree that people should leave a comment.

Comment: The link between the input and the desired output is completely unclear. What logic governs "merging" `[4, 4, 4, 4]` and `[4, 4, 4]` to get `[4]`? What if I had to merge `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[1, 2, 3]`? What about `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[5, 6, 7]`?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: It's not completely unclear, it's possible to make a reason guess and `set` based solutions should be able to deal with cases like those latter two you give just fine even though the OP doesn't have anything similar in their example.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a `set` as the `default_factory` attribute, as sets don't preserve duplicate elements:

```
d1 = defaultdict(set)
```

To convert your existing `defaultdict`s to use `sets`, try this:

```
defaultdict(set, {key: set(value) for key, value in d1.iteritems()})
```

And for old Python versions:

```
defaultdict(set, dict((key, set(value)) for key, value in d1.iteritems()))
```

Comment: In converting the existing dictionary of list into set I am getting an error                                                           d3 = defaultdict(set, {key: set(value) for key, value in d1.iteritems()})
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're probably using a version of Python below 2.7. See my update.

Comment: the d3 is  defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'A': set([4]), 'S': 
the d4 is  defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'A': set([4]), 'B': set([2]), '[]': set([4])}) 
Now How can I get the value of key 'A' in d3 to be just 4 instead of set([4]

Comment: My bad. You have to convert it to a list: `list(d3['A'])[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
d1.update(d2)
for val in d1.values():
    if len(val) > 1:
        val[:] = [val[0]]
```

Comment: FYI it doesn't work, and it modifies `d1` instead of producing a separate merged `defaultdict(list)` result in `d3`. The `for` loop does nothing to the values of `d1`.

Comment: @martineau Did you test it, what doesn't work? I don't have python installed on the laptop on which I'm working now (that's why I wrote untested). I know it modifies `d1` but why is this a problem? I supposed that `d1` and `d2` weren't needed anymore. And if I recall correctly, the values of `d1` do get modified, because they are lists (ints or tuples wouldn't have worked).

Comment: This is the final value of `d1: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [4, 4, 4], 'S': [1], 'B': [2], '[]': [4, 4]})`.

Comment: @martineau Oh, well I guess I have to look into this then, clearly my memory failed me...

Comment: You can try using one of the online Python interpreters, like [this one](http://codepad.org/).

Comment: You need something like `for key,val in d1.iteritems():` and `d1[key] = [val[0]]` in the `for` loop (ignoring the changing of `d1` issue).

Comment: Although you're intuition about the lists being modifiable does seem to make sense, it's not working that way in this case. I'm going to look into the matter further myself when I have a chance.

Comment: If the `val = [val[0]]` is replaced with `val[:] = [val[0]]` in the `for` loop, then `d1` _will_ be modified as you intended -- otherwise a new value is just being assigned to the variable `val` rather than to the list to which it currently refers.

Comment: @martineau thanks for your help and looking further into this! I don't know if you were the one who downvoted my answer (which was fully legit at that time), but if your were, would you consider undoing your vote since it's working know? (btw, it's 'your intuition', not 'you're' :D)

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you said you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = defaultdict(list, {'A': [4, 4, 4, 4], 'S': [1], 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
print 'the d1 is ', d1
d2 = defaultdict(list, {'A': [4, 4, 4], 'B': [2], '[]': [4, 4], 'C': [1, 2, 3]})
print 'the d2 is ', d2

d3 = defaultdict(list, dict((key, set(value) if len(value) > 1 else value)
                                for key, value in d1.iteritems()))
d3.update((key, list(d3[key].union(set(value)) if key in d3 else value))
                                for key, value in d2.iteritems())
print
print 'the d3 is ', d3
```

Output:

```
the d1 is  defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [4, 4, 4, 4], 'S': [1], 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
the d2 is  defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [4, 4, 4], 'C': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [2], '[]': [4, 4]})

the d3 is  defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [4], 'S': [1], 'B': [2], 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4], '[]': [4, 4]})
```

Note that I added a list keyed with `'C'` to both `d1` and `d2` to show what happens for a possibility not mentioned in your question -- so I don't know if it's what you'd want to happen or not.